# Sine graph in dots in Maple

Tags: plot, visualization, maple, trigonometry, amplitude

I'd like to create a top view of a sine graph in dots in Maple, such that the max height is shown with the dots closest together and then the min is shown with the dots furthest apart. It can be lines rather than dots.

Is it possible in Maple? I can use MATLAB too if someone only knows how to do it in MATLAB.

I tried this:

```
plot3d(sin(x),linestyle=dot);
```

and this is what I get (I have moved it so that it is top view):

[image: Fig1]

but I want something like this:

[image: Fig2]

or this (sine graph below the dots aligned with the max/min):

[image: Fix3]

Comment: Please upload a sketch of the desired solution + explain what's wrong with what you tried ("not what I want" is not a good problem statement).

Comment: Yes, it's much less vague now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the following is close to what you want then you can fiddle with the distribution. (eg. to get more spread at the low end)

I wasn't sure whether you tried a top-view of a 3D plot because that's what you wanted, or because it was one way to get something like the 2D plot. So I'll do both.

Based on your image it looks to me like you don't just want a sequence with the y-values equi-spaced. Let us know if that's not the case.

```
restart:

Mx:=Statistics:-RandomVariable(PDF=(x->(sin(x)^1+1.25)/2.25)):
My:=Statistics:-RandomVariable(Uniform(0,1)):

G2D:=proc(r::range(realcons), N::posint)
       local v,w;
       v:=Vector[column](Statistics:-Sample(Mx,N,
                            method=[envelope,updates=300,range=r]));
       w:=Vector[column](Statistics:-Sample(My,N));
       <v|w>;
     end proc:

G3D:=proc(r::range(realcons), N::posint)
       local v,w;
       v:=Vector[column](Statistics:-Sample(Mx,N,
                            method=[envelope,updates=300,range=r]));
       w:=Vector[column](Statistics:-Sample(My,N));
       <v|w|map(sin,v)>;
end proc:

a,b := -5*Pi, 5*Pi:

plots:-display(
  seq(plot(G2D(a..b, 150),style=point,
           symbolsize=7,symbol=solidcircle),
      i=0..1, 0.05),
  view=[a..b, default],
  tickmarks=[piticks,decimalticks]
);
```

[image]

```
# top view of 3D plot
plots:-pointplot3d(G3D(a..b, 3000),
                   color=black, symbolsize=7,
                   orientation=[-90,0,0],
                   view=[a..b, default, default],
                   tickmarks=[piticks,default,default]);
```

[image]

You could also adjust or remove the tickmarks, y-range, color, etc.

[update] I'm not sure whether the followup request is for a stacked 2D or 3D plot.  Here's something in 2D.

```
restart:

Mx:=Statistics:-RandomVariable(PDF=(x->(sin(x)^1+1.25)/2.25)):
My:=Statistics:-RandomVariable(Uniform(0,4)):

G2D:=proc(r::range(realcons), N::posint)
       local v,w;
       v:=Vector[column](Statistics:-Sample(Mx,N,
                            method=[envelope,updates=300,range=r]));
       w:=Vector[column](Statistics:-Sample(My,N));
       <v|map(`+`,w,1)>;
     end proc:

a,b := -5*Pi, 5*Pi:

plots:-display(
 seq(plot(G2D(a..b, 150),style=point,
           symbolsize=7,symbol=solidcircle),
      i=0..1, 0.05),
  plot(sin(x),x=a..b),
  view=[a..b, default],
  tickmarks=[piticks,[-1,1]]
);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Can I also ask, is it possible to have it next to (above) a normal sine graph. I can only manage to get it side by side, and I want to show the max point of the graph with the most dense region on the dots, and the min with the most spread out. If that makes sense. I added an image in the question so show what I mean. Thanks

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want for your followup. I've added something to my post. Please clarify much more, if it's not what you're after. Or do you want something 3D. (You didn't address that query in my Answer...)

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. But this is exactly what I needed, thank you. No it wasn't meant to be 3D, I just need a top view of the dots and then a side view of the sine graph, which is you have given perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you also want a MATLAB solution:

```
x = 0:2*pi/250:8*pi; % change '250' to change density
y = sin(x);

Y = arrayfun(@(ii) rand(1,round((y(ii)+1.2)*10)), (1:length(y)), 'UniformOutput', false);  % floor and ceil also possible (changes density)
X = arrayfun(@(ii) x(ii)*ones(1,length(Y{ii})), (1:length(x)), 'UniformOutput', false);

figure;
hold on;
p=cellfun(@scatter,X,Y);
xlim([0 8*pi])
set(gca, 'Visible','off') % delete axis

for ii=1:length(p)
    set(p(ii),'Marker', '.', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'k', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k');  % make black dots
end
```

result:

[image: result]

---

UPDATE:

The sine wave is already created for the construction of the dots, so only a small adaptation is needed to add the sine to the plot:

```
x = 0:2*pi/250:8*pi; % change '250' to change density
y = sin(x);

Y = arrayfun(@(ii) 2*rand(1,round((y(ii)+1.2)*10))+1.1, (1:length(y)), 'UniformOutput', false);  % floor and ceil also possible (changes density)
X = arrayfun(@(ii) x(ii)*ones(1,length(Y{ii})), (1:length(x)), 'UniformOutput', false);

figure;
hold on;
p=cellfun(@scatter,X,Y);
hold on
plot(x,y)
xlim([0 8*pi])
set(gca, 'Visible','off') % delete axis

for ii=1:length(p)
    set(p(ii),'Marker', '.', 'MarkerFaceColor', 'k', 'MarkerEdgeColor', 'k');  % make black dots
end
```

which gives

[image: result with sine]

Comment: Thanks for this. I was just asking the other person if it is possible to have a normal sine graph below this dotted image, with the max and min inline with the dots. I tried doing it but I can only get it to go side by side. I will update the question to show a picture of what I mean. Thanks a lot however. I would prefer to use MatLab than Maple, but I doubt it is can be done in MatLab, I think it can only be done in Maple

Comment: @Jerry It only takes some minor changes to add the sine wave. Please see the update.